# eclipse and maven global central repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

[image: picture]Hello!

My question is related to eclipse and maven integration, maven repositories and global index update from central mirror.

The quiz is:
Let's supose that I don't have specified any special mirror, nor
{maveninstallationfolder}\conf\settings.xml
neither
{user-home}.m2\settings.xml

So then, why or how eclipse '*maven repositories*' tab decides to fetch central at
*repo.maven.apache.org/maven2*
or
*repo1.maven.org/maven2*
?

Which settings.xml is reloading eclipse when I click on '*reload settings*' button?

I ask this because I have two different eclipse installations ('indigo' at work, 'juno' at home).
At home when I click on '*update index*' it works ok. It updates it from central mirror *repo.maven.apache.org*
At work, doing the same operation it always fails trying to update it from *repo1.maven.org* (I don't know neither I care if because of firewall or proxy issues)
I would like to know how to change it and force it to fetch it from one or another.

I attach a picture to clarify

thanks in advance

Comment: in addition, it could be a decisive clue, why in one eclipse without defining any mirror in any settings.xml under 'maven repositories' tab it takes as central=repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and in the other it takes as central=repo1.maven.org/maven2  

its very misterious

Answer (score 3):

If you have a preferred central repo or if you are using a company maven proxy (like nexus or artifactory) you can set it in the user settings.xml. You may have to create this file. This is normally in `~/.m2` on linux or `c:\Users\YourUser\.m2` on Win7 or `c:\Documents and Settings\YourUser\.m2` on WinXP (IIRC). Note that this is the same place as your local repostitory base folder.

When I create a new settings.xml on a machine that doesn't have one, I go to the maven2 documentations web pages, find the sample settings.xml that is there and copy it to a new file I create.

There is a global `settings.xml` in `$M2_HOME\conf` but it usually isn't changed from the default. It does document all the sections you can add to your `settings.xml` since both have the same sections. (If you are using the embedded version of maven in something like MyEclipse or the maven eclipse plugin, I don't know where they put it.)

For another question, if you need to configure Maven to use a corporate proxy to get out of the company network to maven central, you can put that information in your user `settings.xml` file--the same one you create to set the URL to use.

You may have different versions of Maven running on the two machines. That would explain the different names for central. But the two names both point to the same place.